# R: how to write a wrapper for a function calling another function

Tags: r

I use the function caRamel from the package with the same name. The function takes another function my_func as an argument....

```
caRamel(
  fn=my_func,
  other_caRamel_parameters...
)
```

my_func is a function taking a unique parameter i (by design, mandatory and given by the caRamel function):

```
my_func <- function(i) {
  require(somelib)
  my_path = "C:/myfolder/"
  do things with i
  ...
}
```

By design, there is no way to pass further arguments to the my_func function inside the caRamel function and I have to hard code everything like the my_path variable for example inside my_func.

However, I would like to be able to pass my_path and others variables as parameters in the caRamel function like so:

```
caRamel(
  fn=my_func,
  other_caRamel_parameters...,
  my_path="C:/myfolder/", ...
)
```

with:

```
my_func <- function(i, my_path) {
  require(somelib)
  my_path = my_path
  do things with i
  ...
}
```

I was then wondering if it was possible to write a "wrapper" in this case so that further parameters can be passed to my_func? What could be the options to achieve that?

Comment: You need a function factory?  I think it could be easier with a more reproducible example. Otherwise, you can always use `...` to pass other args to any other function.

Comment: Hi, it seems not. If I do that with the caRamel function, I get an unused argument error: Error in caRamel(... unused argument (my_path = "...")...

Comment: We can't really tell what you want to do without any example.

Answer (score 1):

We can use {purrr} and {rlang} in a custom `myCaRamel` function which only takes the ellipsis `...` as argument.

First we capture the dots with `rlang::list2(...)`.

Then we get all formals of the `caRamel` function as names with `rlang::fn_fmls_names`.

Now we differentiate between arguments which go into the `caRamel` function and those which go into your custom function.

We use `purrr::partial` to supply the argument which go into your `my_fun`.

Then we call the original `caRamel` function using the partial function we created together with the arguments that go in to `caRamel`.

In the example below I `rlang::expr` in the last call to show that it is working. Please delete the `expr()` around the last call to make it actually work.

The downside is that **every** argument needs to be correctly named. Unnamed arguments and partial matching won't work. Further, if `my_fun` and `caRamel` contain arguments with similar names they only go into `caRamel` and won't reach `my_fun`.

```r
library(purrr)
library(rlang)
library(caRamel)


my_fun <- function(x, my_path) {
  # use my_path
  # and some x
}

myCaRamel <- function(...) {
  
  dots <- rlang::list2(...)
  
  caramel_args <- rlang::fn_fmls_names(caRamel)
  caramel_args_wo_fun <- caramel_args["func" != caramel_args]
  other_args <- names(dots)[!names(dots) %in% caramel_args]
  
  my_fn <- dots[["func"]]
  
  my_fn <- purrr::partial(my_fn, !!! dots[other_args])
  
  rlang::expr( # just to show correct out put - delete this line 
    caRamel(func = my_fn,
          !!! dots[names(dots) %in% caramel_args_wo_fun])
    )    # delete this line 
                         
}

myCaRamel(func = my_fun,
          my_path = "C:/myfolder/",
          nvar = 10)

#> caRamel(func = my_fn, nvar = 10)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>